# javax.json strange behavior

Tags: java, json

I don't understand why the last row of this code return a empty string.

```
Map<String, JsonObjectBuilder> HASH_MAP = new HashMap<>();

JsonObjectBuilder one = Json.createObjectBuilder();
one.add("test1","test1");
HASH_MAP.put("one", one);

JsonObjectBuilder two = Json.createObjectBuilder();
two.add("test2","test2");
HASH_MAP.put("two", two);

JsonObjectBuilder toReturn = Json.createObjectBuilder();
JsonArrayBuilder l1 = Json.createArrayBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, JsonObjectBuilder> l : HASH_MAP.entrySet()) {
    l1.add(l.getValue());
}

toReturn.add("l1", l1);
toReturn.add("otherParam", "value2");
String strJSON = toReturn.build().toString();
System.out.println("JSON1: " + strJSON);
System.out.println("JSON2: " + HASH_MAP.get("one").build().toString());
```

This is the output:

```
Info:   JSON1: {"l1":[{"test1":"test1"},{"test2":"test2"}],"otherParam":"value2"}
Info:   JSON2: {}
```

I am espetting that the second JSON is `{"test1":"test1"}`. I am wrong?
The problem seems to be link with the `.build()` function that sets all the *valueMap* of elements added to the `HASH_MAP` to null (see the image).
[image]

How can I leave the value inside the `HASH_MAP` untouched?

Comment: Try to test that: put your System.out.println("JSON2: " + HASH_MAP.get("one").build().toString()); after the line HASH_MAP.put("one", one);

Comment: This is the output: JSON: {"test1":"test1"} # JSON: {"l1":[{},{"test2":"test2"}],"otherParam":"value2"} # JSON: {}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After `build()`ing a `JsonObject` from a `JsonObjectBuilder` the builder is *cleared* to be ready for reuse. To illustrate this:

```
JsonObjectBuilder b = Json.createObjectBuilder();
b.add("foo", "bar");
JsonObject o = b.build();
JsonObject p = b.build();
System.out.println(o.toString()); // {"foo":"bar"}
System.out.println(p.toString()); // {}
```

When you do

```
l1.add(l.getValue()); // l.getValue() is (JsonObjectBuilder) one at some time
```

`build()` is called *implicitly* on `one`, hence it is emptied.

Then here:

```
System.out.println("JSON2: " + HASH_MAP.get("one").build().toString());
```

you build the representation of an empty `JsonObject`.

To migitate this, you could for example store JsonObjects instead of JsonObjectBuilders in your hashmap:

```
Map<String, JsonObject> HASH_MAP = new HashMap<>();

JsonObjectBuilder one = Json.createObjectBuilder();
one.add("test1","test1");
HASH_MAP.put("one", one.build());

JsonObjectBuilder two = Json.createObjectBuilder();
two.add("test2","test2");
HASH_MAP.put("two", two.build());

JsonObjectBuilder toReturn = Json.createObjectBuilder();
JsonArrayBuilder l1 = Json.createArrayBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, JsonObject> l : HASH_MAP.entrySet()) {
    l1.add(l.getValue());
}

toReturn.add("l1", l1);
toReturn.add("otherParam", "value2");
String strJSON = toReturn.build().toString();
System.out.println("JSON1: " + strJSON);
System.out.println("JSON2: " + HASH_MAP.get("one").toString());
```

Now it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the call to `build()` flush the value stored in your object `one` JSonObjectBuilder, so you can call only one time the method build(), If you call it again you go to have the representation of an empty `JSonObject`. Ex:

```
one.add("test1","test1");   
System.out.println(one.build())
System.out.println(one.build())
```

the output:

```
{"test1":"test1"}
{}
```

If you really want to call it again, you have to add again the value that you want. Ex:

```
one.add("test1","test1");
System.out.println(one.build())
one.add("test1","test1")
System.out.println(one.build())
```

the output:

```
{"test1":"test1"}
{"test1":"test1"}
```

As @Ctx says, you could put in your map JsonObjects instead of JsonObjectBuilders, so put as value of your map the JsonObject  returned by the call of the method build().

Ex:

```
HASH_MAP.put("one", one.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, the provided implementation of JsonObjectBuilder flushes when you call build().

The best solution is to implement your own, non-flushing builder, based on the JsonObjectBuilder interface:

```
public final class NfJsonObjectBuider implements JsonObjectBuilder {

    private Map<String, Object> values = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public JsonObjectBuilder add(String name, JsonValue value) {
        this.values.put(name, value);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonObjectBuilder add(String name, String value) {
        this.values.put(name, value);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonObjectBuilder add(String name, BigInteger value) {
        this.values.put(name, value);
        return this;
    }
    //other add(...) methods with the same implementation

    @Override
    public JsonObject build() {
        //HERE: reuse their building logic.
        final JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        for(final Entry<String, Object> pair : this.values.entrySet()) {
            this.addToBuilder(pair, builder);
        }
        return builder.build();
    }

    private void addToBuilder(Entry<String, Object> pair, JsonObjectBuilder 
 builder) {
        if(pair.getValue() instanceof JsonValue) {
            builder.add(pair.getKey(), (JsonValue) pair.getValue());
        }
        if(pair.getValue() instanceof String) {
            builder.add(pair.getKey(), (String) pair.getValue());
        }
        if(pair.getValue() instanceof Boolean) {
            builder.add(pair.getKey(), (Boolean) pair.getValue());
        }
        //A couuple more ifs to cover all the add(...) methods.
    }
}
```

The whole article here: http://www.amihaiemil.com/2017/06/14/non-flushable-jsonobjectbuilder.html

Comment: It is highly recommended to bring your entire solution here, links get broken.